# Catch Errors in interacive Powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, interactive

if try to do something in ineracvie powershell, is it possible to catch a speific error ? 
i mean:

```
powershell.exe
PS C:>_
PS C:>fuu
fuu: this is not a cmdlet .... BLA BLA BLA
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fuu:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This is the normal behavior of ineractive powershell.
Can i put somethin in my Profile.ps1 or so that everything stay like this but for an SPECIFIC error, as example these CommandNotFoundException, only on these error i change the behavior of the powershell? maybe a new wirte-host or something else.

```
powershell.exe
PS C:>_
PS C:>fuu
fuu: this is not a cmdlet so CommandNotFoundException and now i behave diffrent my lord
PS C:>_
```

so yes, i know try catch and so on -> IN SCRIPTS but i mean interactivly as default behavior !

thanks

[UPDATE]

To clear things up. the real case is codesigning. ExecutionPolicy is AllSignt and if i forget to sign testcode ofcourse you got the error:

```
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Sicherheitsfehler: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

but in exact this case i dont want this error, i want the question, DO YOU WANT TO SIGN THIS ? Y/N

.... and than do that.

Answer (score 1):

use this structure :

```
$Error.Clear()

fooo

$Errormessage = $Error | Out-String
$Errormessage
```

you will receive :

```
fooo : The term 'fooo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:1
+ fooo
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fooo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

and when you have string you can make parser and make your custom  error handler like

```
$customerror = $Errormessage.reaplace("fooo : The term 'fooo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.","Foo is not functin")

 write-output $customerror
```

Comment: but how i add these to the normal PS behavior ? i dont want to add lines of code to my "fuu" call.  i want to manipulate the error handling of the ineracive shell

Comment: @AnUser your mean editing powershell error by defult? . i don't know it's possible . sorry my friend . i just vote your question to come top question . and if u want i can remove my answer .

Comment: thank you, no dont remove it, maybe it clears somthing a bit up.